# Combining two charts in one div - d3 / css

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm definitely not good at `css` and this kind of stuff.
I have these two plots (jsfiddle examples):

https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/g6vyk7t1/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/rhzkz9gb/16/

And I would like to have them in the same `div`, but not side-by-side, but like in 2x1 (2 lines and 1 column).

So far I'm ending up with this (these data, together, don't make sense but this is just a test):

[image]

I tried to reproduce this behavior here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0tvLdwxz/

But here at least they are in the same line, it looks better.
I would like to be able to have them in the same column, and different lines. I don't know how to do this.

This is the `.css`:

```
.arc text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

.info {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.info h4 {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  color: #777;
}

.info-legend {
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

.info-legend i {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get from your description, you want the svg containers behave like a `block` instead of `inline-block`. One way to implement this is to set the `width` of `svg` to `100%`, so that the width will be the same as the `div` container, although the height is the same as in your code.

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dtz427gu/1/)

If you want to center align the chart, you can use transform-translate accordingly on svg containers.

Besides, set width to 100% could be helpful if you want to implement responsive chart with attributes such as `preserveAspectRatio`.

Comment: I liked your solution because I don't restrict the behavior of the other `svg`s that I may have but I'm ending up with a very large div that I'm not being able to adjust.

Comment: @pceccon if you set the width to '100%', it is also easier to make the charts more responsive, for instance, you can use svg's `preserveAspectRatio` attribute to control how to scale or translate the chart.

Comment: I just don't know how I'm ending up with a so large width and how to control it. It's larger then the larges plot that is stack-bar.

Comment: @pceccon I suppose that you meant the div container has a large width? That's because there is no width value for `.info` in CSS file, hence the div will be 100% width of the `body`. I added a width(450px) in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dtz427gu/3/). Hope this is what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
svg {
  display: block;
}
```